# Update state variable within loop in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got two titles and two subTitles when I am looping an array e.g.**props.tashlumExtraTitle**

I want to update each title and subTitle in one bottom sheet.

i got two title from **textTitle["@TEUR"]** and two subTitle from **textTitle["@SCHUM_HODSHI"] + "ש”ח"**

```
let titleText = "";
  let subTitleText = "";
  
    props.tashlumExtraTitle.forEach((textTitle) => {
      titleText = textTitle["@TEUR"];
      console.log("title-->", titleText);
      subTitleText = textTitle["@SCHUM_HODSHI"] + "ש”ח";
      console.log("subtitle-->", subTitleText);
    });
```

BottomSheet:---

```
<RBSheet
        ref={helpSheet}
        closeOnDragDown={true}
        closeOnPressMask={true}
        height={hp(60)}
        customStyles={{
          wrapper: {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(52,52,52,0.8)",
          },
          draggableIcon: {
            backgroundColor: "#d3d6dc",
          },
          container: {
            borderRadius: 15,
          },
        }}
      >
        <Container>
          <HelpComponentContainer
            title={titleText}
            subTitle={subTitleText}
          />
        </Container>
```

[image: When a user clicks on the title and gets the bottom sheet, then the same title and subtitle should be displayed on the bottom sheet.]

When a user clicks on the title and gets the bottom sheet, then the same title and subtitle should be displayed on the bottom sheet.

How can I get these updated values for title and subTitle as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cause a re render when the values update.So the screen re renders and shows the updated values. You can do this with `useState` hook. So do this.

```js
const [titleText,setTitleText] = React.useState("")
const [subTitleText,setSubTitleText]  = React.useState("")

// Runs every time props.tashlumList changes
React.useEffect(()=>{
 if (props.tashlumList) {
    props.tashlumExtraTitle.forEach((textTitle) => {
      setTitleText(textTitle["@TEUR"]);
      setSubTitleText(textTitle["@SCHUM_HODSHI"] + "ש”ח");
    });
  }
},[props.tashlumList])
```

**Read this** (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: I tried but getting error i.e.too many re-renders.@carlosdafield

Comment: Try this then I updated the anwser. Also whats `props.tashlumList1` is it just a list

Comment: yes..i tried but same error i got and what i need to put in title of <HelpComponentContainer>

Comment: props.tashlumList this is just a list,it is not important..

Comment: Is props.tashlumList always changing. I need some context in when you want to change titleText and subTitleText. Because if it's always changing the useEffect will always rerender

Comment: If you put all the code for this in a expo snack (look it up online). It will be much easier for us to answer this question.

Comment: i edited my code...just look that and give the solutions..

Comment: So you're either looping through a 2d array and setting titleText and subTitleText to be the last element or you're reseting the same variable each time. Either way it doesn't make sense

Comment: if i am clicking  on the first row i want to display only those row title on the bottom sheet.